# Google Analytics API: Not getting reports

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-java-client

I'm using google anlaytics in emails tracking. I can see the hits(opens) in "RealTime" section of Analytics Page. Few months back when I used this, it used to take around 15 mins to get the reports from API .
But now even after several hours, I cannot access anything through API

What can I do now to get the reports??

Comment: Are you talking about the website or the API here?   It takes 24 - 48 hours for data to appear in the audience reports.

Comment: @DalmTo I'm bothering about API . How much time will it take??

Comment: Unless you are reading from the Real-time API the answer is probably the same it can take time for data to show up in the core reporting api.

Comment: But since when is this happening? I've run my same set up 4 months back and It is working fine with a delay of 15 minutes.

Comment: It really depends on the amount of data being sent.  Google says that it takes 24 -48 hours for data to be processed they wont guarantee you anything faster.    See if the data you are after is available in the real-time API that is updated quite often but it has limited data.

Comment: I can see them in real-time reports.

Comment: Then make sure you are requesting data from the Real-time api https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/